# Sending cookies with request in python with byte-type data

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, byte

I have a dictionary with the following format:

```
{
"cookie_name": b"xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx",
"cookie_name2": b"xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx",
...
}
```

I am attempting to use `requests` to send a request to the website with the cookie data.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import requests
cookies = {...}
r = requests.post('https://linktowebsite.com', cookies=cookies)
```

However, I'm met with an error instead:

```
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\omaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\omaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 471, in prepare_request
    cookies = cookiejar_from_dict(cookies)
  File "C:\Users\omaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 537, in cookiejar_from_dict
    cookiejar.set_cookie(create_cookie(name, cookie_dict[name]))
  File "C:\Users\omaro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 352, in set_cookie
    and cookie.value.startswith('"')
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

I've tried encoding/decoding with UTF-8 as well as converting to string but nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: sample cookie value:
`` {'ASP.NET_SessionId': b'v10K\xfe:\xe0\x18\xad\x08\xd3\xe0\xe8\x12\xe7`\xe7\x15lib?\xd2\xe7oX\xb4jvT7\xd5\xad\xb6\xa0 \x03G\xe1W\xb0-\xf3\x0bh\xd0\xccOI7\x10\xe7.\xaa\xbf'} ``

Here's how to reproduce my dictionary:

```
def get_cookies(ff_cookies, col_names):
    cj = http.cookiejar
    con = sqlite3.connect(ff_cookies)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT "+", ".join(col_names)+" FROM cookies")  # gets data for SQLlite file
    
    # iterates through all columns and adds it to list
    cookieList = [item for item in cur.fetchall()]
    cookies_dict = {}
    for name in col_names:
        cookies_dict[name] = []

    # formats dictionary using above list
    cookies_dict_keys = list(cookies_dict)
    for cookie in cookieList:
        for i in range(len(cookie)):
            cookies_dict[cookies_dict_keys[i]].append(cookie[i])

    return cookies_dict
```

Where `ff_cookies` is the path to the file and `col_names` are the names of the columns in the SQL file as a list of strings

The return value of this function is then fed into the `requests.post` function

It is also important to note that this SQL file was found in my edge browser files: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Network\Cookies`

Comment: can you update the code with a sample cookie in byte format?

Comment: Please add https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with URL and maybe we could help you.

Comment: @Charchit sure, I've just added one now

Comment: @Charchit just edited my post with some more useful information, if you need anything else just let me know

Comment: did the answer below work?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like wherever you got the cookies from do no not want you reading them.  You can use [binascii.hexlify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) to convert this binary data to hexadecimal, and then decode it so it can be passed as cookie value:

Try this code:

```
import requests
import binascii

val = b"v10K\xfe:\xe0\x18\xad\x08\xd3\xe0\xe8\x12\xe7`\xe7\x15lib?\xd2\xe7oX\xb4jvT7\xd5\xad\xb6\xa0 \x03G\xe1W\xb0-\xf3\x0bh\xd0\xccOI7\x10\xe7.\xaa\xbf"
val = binascii.hexlify(val)
val = val.decode()
print(val)
cookies = {"ASP.NET_SessionId": val}


r = requests.post('https://google.com', cookies=cookies)
```

**Output**

```
7631304bfe3ae018ad08d3e0e812e760e7156c69623fd2e76f58b46a765437d5adb6a0200347e157b02df30b68d0cc4f493710e72eaabf
```

However, I will encourage you to check whether this is the case for all cookie values you have found. Decode them using this method and see if the resulting values make sense (because of the off chance that they are not actually hexadecimals).